# Read contents of a page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, http, dom

I am building a chrome plugin which gets triggered when a particular site is opened.
After the page is loaded the plugin should read the contents of the current page opened.

(Assume that I always try to open a page which has plain text just like raw code in GitHub ).
I know how to get content calling a GET in xmlHttpRequest. And print function is just to call for a printer to print out the contents.

Yet I want to store the contents of the current page.

Edit: 
Got a solution on storing the page elements.

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Another bottleneck:
If the page content is too heavy, is it good to store in a variable?
Or is it possible to stream in the page for operations.